# Does IOS Have "Complete Action With" Dialog like android for opening direction apps

Tags: ios

How to achieve "open with" dialog when opening a direction, user can select use apple map, google map, waze and others

Comment: you can archive this using url scheme.

Comment: following is link for implementing google map : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme